# Read MemoryStream into Byte[] chunk at a time for processing

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am passing a MemoryStream to a function - this could potentially end up being very large in size. This then needs to be split off into a small byte[] for processing and then added back to a stream. In my previous implementation I had roughly the following:

```
byte[] output = new byte[stream.Length];
output = stream.ToArray();
byte[] processingArray = new byte[16];

int index = 0;
int chunks = output / 16;
for(int i = 0; i < chunks; i++){
  for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
     processingArray[x] = output[x + index];
  }
  //do the processing on the array here
  index += 16;
}
```

I want to avoid having to use .ToArray() as this seems like a resource waste to me.
How would I go about extracting 16 bytes at a time from the memorystream, processing it and then grabbing the next 16 bytes?

Thanks

Comment: For a `MemoryStream` instance, the contents of the stream already occupy RAM

Comment: BTW: creating the output as new byte[strem.Length] and directly after that drop it by assigning the result of stream.ToArray() does not make much sense. you could just write byte[] output = stream.ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.read.aspx) method to specify a buffer and read block by block:

```
byte[] block = new byte[16];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
```

In the above sample, `bytesRead` contains the number of bytes that was read in the call to `Read`. If there are no more bytes to read, `bytesRead` will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand why you want to extract parts of a `MemoryStream` for memory footprint. The `MemoryStream` itself is already in the memory, so why divide it in chunks?

If you call `ToArray` all the memory is copied, so why not directly write output to a new (Memory)Stream?

If you want to read the stream use this:

```
stream.Position = 0; // go to beginning of stream

byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
while(stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
    // process
}
```

Comment: In essence im working on some novelty encryption and recording audio . The audio is recorded to the memorystream, once it is all recorded I need to pass this information to my encryption function, once the block is encrypted im passing it back to the stream and writing the file

Comment: I posted an update to include the actual reading. Don't forget to go to the beginning of the stream as in the code!

Answer (score 0):

`GetBuffer()` will return the internal array that `MemoryStream` is using. This allows you to bypass `Read()` to make an efficient zero-copy solution:

```
MemoryStream ms;

byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
int offset = ms.Position;
int left = ms.Length - offset;

while(left != 0)
{
    // process buffer starting at offset.
}
```